# Laravel: getting results with repeated records with model query builder

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

I am building a query that gives me user ids:

```
// ... building the $userIdsQuery
$userIds = $userIdsQuery->pluck('user_id');
```

As an array like this:

```
[12, 13, 14, 14]
```

So when I get the users with these user ids from model:

```
User::whereIn('id', $userIds)->get();
```

Expectedly gives me the three users with ids [12, 13, 14]

**BUT I want the user with id 14 twice!**

That's the matter.

Is there a nice / clean way to do this?

Or do I have to put the users in some array / collection one by one?

Answer (score 1):

Use `foreach` loops:

```
$user = array();
$userIds = [12, 13, 14, 14];

foreach ($userIds as $key => $userId) {
   $user[$key] = User::find($userId);
}
```

Comment: I did like this first (with collection), then I decided use a database view where I join two tables and get the results from there.